# Backbone not firing render event

Tags: events, backbone.js, view, collections, reset

I have tried to created two views and change collection in different situations. I dont know how to setup this.collection.bind so it raises event render on every collection change.

There are 3 situations where I expect view `BusinessListView` to fire `render`

1. `this.businesslist.collection = new Businesses([{ name: '1'}, { name: '2' }]);`
2. `this.businesslist.set();` which calls `this.collection = new Businesses([{ name: '3'}, { name: '4' }]);`
3. `this.search_location = new SearchLocation();` which is different view, then send collection to view `BusinessListView`

I was expecting to see data in console on 1 and 2, it doesnt work. If I add .render() manually I can see collection has changed. Could you please explain how this works?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Alex this is fully working solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/feronovak/RAPjM/

```
var App = {
    run: function() {
        this.businesslist = new BusinessListView(); 
        this.businesslist.collection = new Businesses([{ name: '1'}, { name: '2' }]);
        // this.businesslist.render(); // uncomment to see collection change 
        this.businesslist.set();

        this.search_location = new SearchLocation();
    }
};

Business = Backbone.Model.extend({});
Businesses = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:  Business
});

BusinessListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.collection = new Businesses();
        this.collection.bind("reset", this.render(), this);
    },
    render: function() {
        console.log(this.collection.toJSON());
    },
    set: function()
    {
        this.collection = new Businesses([{ name: '3'}, { name: '4' }]);
        // this.render(); // uncomment to see collection change 
    }
});

SearchLocation = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#search",
    initialize: function() {
        this.sendData();
    },
    sendData: function() {
        //  Send [{ name: '5'}, { name: '6' }] to this.businesslist  = new Businesses([{ name: '5'}, { name: '6' }]);
    }
});

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    App.run();
});
```

Comment: Does not changing collection call reset event? I hoped that if I change collection manually (only in this example) render would be called.

Comment: Deleted my last comment as it was incorrect I guess. Your jsfiddle shows that the render method is run.

Comment: By creating a new object, the listener disappears. So you're just not listening to the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you keep setting this.collection reference to different instances. it wont "reset" because you never actually reset the object referenced in initialize.

instead of:

```
set: function()
    {
        this.collection = new Businesses([{ name: '3'}, { name: '4' }]);
    }
```

try:

```
set: function()
    {
        this.collection.reset([{ name: '3'}, { name: '4' }]);
    }
```

and remove in run:

```
this.businesslist.collection = new Businesses([{ name: '1'}, { name: '2' }]);
```

Example Here: http://jsfiddle.net/aXJ9x/1/

Comment: It has not triggered this.render() either. This line (this.businesslist.collection) is there on purpose, I am trying to see how different methods can be used to modify collections. Could you fork jsfiddle to show working example?

Comment: Fiddle added to bottom of post

Comment: Thanks, works great. What would I have to do to be able to call collection 5,6 from SearchLocation view?

Comment: Normally something like sendData would be event driven. Normally you would never call sendData in initialize, but as the result of an event / callback. http://jsfiddle.net/aXJ9x/2/ to simulate such event. In this case, I have called sendData from run, just to make life easy.